# Authentication with Mifare Ultralight C

Tags: authentication, nfc, mifare

I am wanting to authenticate with the Mifare Ultralight C tag, I have written the key into the tag already, the key is 0x"000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F", so I have to write backward like this into pages of 0x2C to 0x2F

```
uint8_t buffer1[] = {0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04};
uint8_t buffer2[] = {0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};
uint8_t buffer3[] = {0x0F, 0x0E, 0x0D, 0x0C};
uint8_t buffer4[] = {0x0B, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x08};
// write the data
success = nfc->mifareultralight_WritePage(0x2C, buffer1); 
success &= nfc->mifareultralight_WritePage(0x2D, buffer2);
success &= nfc->mifareultralight_WritePage(0x2E, buffer3);
success &= nfc->mifareultralight_WritePage(0x2F, buffer4);`
```

But I don't know the command for authentication, can anyone tell me the authentication steps and commands to authenticate with this key?

Comment: No reply :( Does anyone help me please?

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640515/5128464)