# Send APDU command for ultralight C authentication

Tags: apdu, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard, omnikey

I'm trying to authenticate to ultralight c and I'm stuck for a few days on the following: (using OK5321)

I'm able to open the generic session:

```
-> FFA0000703010001
<- 90 00
```

Authenticate:

```
->FFA00005080100F30000641A0000
<-00 00 AF 92 11 26 10 8C 1B 8E 3F 90 00
```

The third step I have tried the following: `//random rndbA:  0xA8, 0xAF, 0x3B, 0x25, 0x6C, 0xC7, 0x5E, 0x40`

```
`-> FFA00005180100F30000640078C4B4CC65D91E62AFA8AF3B256CC75E40` //combined the first authenticate result with the rndbA and I get this result:

<- 08 04 00 90 00
```

Then when I try to read I receive an error.

Am I doing any step wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Authenticating with NXP MiFare Ultralight C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438554/android-authenticating-with-nxp-mifare-ultralight-c). With generic session [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660223/5128464)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I have looked into both of those Q&A and I did not understand from where it coming the rndbA if it's a random value that we add or is something that the reader answers.

Another thing is I can send the A1 00 mentioned there to the reader even using the HID tool to do it I receive always an error:

PC/SC Error: Unable to send command (0x001F)!

Comment: `rndA` is a random nonce generated by terminal (your code). `rndB` is a random nonce generated by the card. See section "3DES authentication" in the MF0ICU2 document. Your second frame seems malformed -- it does not have the correct structure (i.e. -- AFh || ek(RndA || RndB') ). See example log trace in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660223/5128464) linked above...

Comment: @vlp, I'm able to come to

OPEN GENERIC SESSION
 -> FFA0000703010001
 <- 9000
AUTHENTICATE
 => 1A00
 -> FFA00005080100F30000641A0000
 <- 0000AF4BDA4E34B5D04A019000

Then I can't understand which is the next APDU command that I must send.

As far as I understand when reading the MF0ICU2 document, section 7.5.55 (3DES Auth).

I need to concatenate the RndA with RndB and enciphered with the Key.

Now, how can I get the RndA? Is rotating the RndB left by 8 bits.

Thanks

Comment: `RndA` is a [random nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) **you** generate. In the linked code it is generated by a SecureRandom instance. For test purposes (and only for test purposes, not for production) you can make something up -- e.g. `0011223344556677`

Comment: Thanks, this should be a "secure static" string on the code and is nothing that is generated as the RndB, correct?

So the third command, should be the concatenation of RndA and RndB?

Comment: Both `RndA` and `RndB` are randomly generated nonces. `RndA` is generated by your code and `RndB` is generated by the card. What should be in the >third command< is clearly written in the abovementioned document and implemented in the linked answer...Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for your help authentication is done correctly now @vlp!

I'm trying to form the write command FFA2. Which is always giving me an error related with function not supported. Can you help me with an example? thanks